# How to detect collision position and that position's texture color in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection, physics

I have a prefab and I use Circlecollider2D for physics operations. I want to detect the color of the contact position of the collided objects ? Is is possible by using Unity's collider classes ?

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a Look at [Texture2D.GetPixel](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html)

You can find the contact point on the collider and then map that to the specific point on the texture.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think the contact point gives me world coordinates of collision. But I need texture coordinates for GetPixel(x, y) function ?

Comment: You need to transform world co-ordinates into pixel co-ordinates. Use Camera.worldToScreenPoint.